# raphael bound image inside path

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have the following simple Raphael code:

```
var paper = Raphael('paper', '512', '512');
    var draggableImage = paper.image("testimage.png", 10, 10 , 80, 80 );
    var path = paper.path("...");
    path.attr({
      id: 'path',
      fill: 'none',
      stroke: '#000000',
      "stroke-width": '1',
      "stroke-linecap": 'butt',
      "stroke-linejoin": 'miter',
      "stroke-opacity": '1'
    }).data('id', 'path');
    paper.freeTransform(draggableImage);
```

I'd like to have `draggableImage` draggable just only into `path`.

Pratically speaking, if, during moving it, you bring it partially outside the path I just want to see only the part which remain into the path.

How can I achieve this tricky stuff?

Comment: Sounds a bit like you may want a clippath or something. Are you tied to using Raphael ? (Wondering if Snap.svg may be a better fit for stuff like that). You could try setting the fill of the path to be that image and see what happens.